# How to demonstrate the uniform continuity of a function in the case it has no limited derivative

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

First of all, I would like to apologize if I make grammatical errors because English is not my mother tongue.
During a lecture at the university my teacher did an exercise that required to find the values of some parameters so that a function would be uniformly continuous.
The function has a bounded derivative in the whole domain regardless of the parameters except in a point of it.
To determine the value of the parameters, my professor has set two conditions:
1) The function must be continuous in the point.
2) The function must have a bounded derivative at that point.

After doing this he considered the exercise solved.

In fact, the bounded derivative implies that the function is Lipschitz continuous and this in turn implies that it is uniformly continuous.

My question is:
There are functions, such as $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ defined in $[0,1]$ that are uniformly continuous but not Lipschitz continuous.
So how did my professor be sure he did not miss similar situations during the course of the exercise?

I would also like to ask you, in case my professor had forgotten about this, how could I find the values of the parameters omitted in his resolution of the exercise.

In case you need it, the function that my professor has examined is the following:
$$\begin{cases}a\cdot\cosh x + b\cdot\cos x + \frac{b}{x-1}&x> 0\\
x + 3b(x-1) + \frac{2a}{x-1}& x \le 0\end{cases}$$

The parameters are $a$, $b$ and the solutions found by the professor are: 
$a = 0$ and $b = 1$.

Comment: On the English - it's mostly fine. You have a few missing periods - it would be easier to read if you closed your sentences properly. (The most important one is in the first paragraph; the others are at ends of lines.) Also, the standard mathematical English for what you called "limited" is "bounded". And now - I'll edit those corrections in, along with prettier math.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. It seems that google translate isn't as perfect as I hoped haha

Comment: I noticed some things on edit. The [help page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) on general formatting should be useful to you. In particular, note that just hitting return for the next line doesn't get you a new line in the output - you need two spaces before the new line for that. There's also a [help page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for the pretty math (LaTeX commands).

Comment: This the first question I posted, thank you very much, I'll take a look at those help page